# Is there an immune deficiency disorder that fits this description?

Tags: immune-system, fatigue, deficiency, adolescents-teenagers, stable-condition

I've been trying to do some research for a writing project, but I need some advice to help me identify what specific things I should be researching, because "immune deficiency" in general brings up a kind of overwhelming number of possible directions to go in. Ideally, I'm hoping to identify a suitable specific diagnosis for a character, or at least narrow down my options, so that I can focus my research more effectively and improve my chances of an accurate portrayal.

The character is a girl in her mid teens, who's had health issues since before she started school. That's set in stone. Anything else is open to adjustment for accuracy, but here's what kind of stuff I had in mind;

- Primary rather than secondary immunodeficiency.
- Severe enough for her to be absent from school fairly regularly
- Not life threatening (at least for the time being)
- She's had to be hospitalised enough times that she's pretty familiar with the process.
- When she *is* in school her illness is rarely (if at all) totally invisible. There might be some restrictions on what she can or can't take part in, she might need some kind of medical equipment, she might display some kind of visible symptoms, maybe she just gets fatigued easily? Whatever it is, it's noticeable to her classmates.

So. Anything in particular come to mind? Anything I should (or shouldn't) be focusing on? Any advice or suggestions would be much appreciated, and could potentially save my brain from imploding after one too many pages of dense and technical medical literature.